# Como hacer dos header, uno estatico y el otro sticky

Tags: bootstrap

Quiere que en el header se quede estatico, pero que al dar scroll solo la parte del menu baje, sin el logo, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera editar y mostrar lo que llevas así tu duda será mejor recibida y de paso evitamos el cierre de la misma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es con css, haciendo uso de un selector descentente.

```
.rd-navbar.rd-navbar--is-stuck .rd-navbar-panel{
   display: none;
}
```

Básicamente, cuando el objeto, en este caso el header, de clase `rd-navbar`, adquiere su otra clase, la del estado "suspendido" por llamarle de alguna manera, que sería `rd-navbar--is-stuck`, el logo, de clase `rd-navbar-panel` se hace invisible y listo.
El código no requiere de más porque los elementos ya están programados de un modo que se adaptaran por sí solos para cubrir el nuevo espacio sobrante.

Si deseas un código css más específico incluye el tipo de elementos, por ejemplo en este caso sería:

```
nav.rd-navbar.rd-navbar--is-stuck div.rd-navbar-panel{
   display: none;
}
```

Con eso quedaría asegurado que solo afecte al logo.